# How to query Azure VMSS instances computer name for flexible orchestration

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set

The az cli command I'm running is:

```
az vmss list-instances --resource-group rg-name --name my-vmss-name --output json
```

returns instances details with `osProfile.computerName` for VMSS running in unified orchestration mode.
But in case of flexible orchestration it returns only basic info like instance name, but not `computerName`.

How can I query the instance details for VM Scale Set running in flexible orchestration mode?

That is only what I have for the flexible vmss:

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx",
    "instanceId": "my_instance1_fc8548e2",
    "location": "northeurope",
    "name": "my_instance1_fc8548e2",
    "resourceGroup": "my-rg",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines",
    "zones": []
  },
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx",
    "instanceId": "my_instance1_fda96383",
    "location": "northeurope",
    "name": "my_instance1_fda96383",
    "resourceGroup": "my-rg",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines",
    "zones": []
  }
```

For the unified vmss I have huge objects with all vm details.
The powerhsell commandlet Get-AzVmssVM also doesn't return osprofile for running VM instances.
The `instanceView=true` option causes 400 error:

```
Operation 'VirtualMachineScaleSets.virtualMachines.GET' is not allowed on Virtual Machine Scale Set
```

Answer (score 0):

The `az vmss list-instances` command does not return the instance details with `osProfile.computerName`.

VMSS Orchestration mode: **Flexible**

[image]

You can use the below command to fetch the computer name for each instance in the VMSS with **flexible** orchestration.

```
vmlist=$(az vmss list-instances --resource-group <RG_name> --name <VMSS_Name> --query [].name -o tsv)
for item in $vmlist
do
    computer_name=$(az vm show -n $item -g <RG_name> --query osProfile.computerName -o tsv)
    echo "The VMSS instance computer name: $computer_name"
done
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**  [Orchestration modes for Virtual Machine Scale Sets in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-orchestration-modes)

Comment: The computer name prefix and computer name are two different things. I need to query the comptuer names for each running instance

Comment: Hi Alexey Ryazhskikh, I have updated my answer to fetch the **computer names** of the instances instead of the **computer name prefix**.

Answer (score 0):

To pull the computer name for each of the instances in VMscaleset in flexible orchestration you can leverage the below script.

```
$vmlist= Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName {ResourceGroupName} -VMScaleSetName {VMScaleSetName} | select -property Name,ResourceGroupName
foreach( $item in $vmlist){
    az vm show -n $item.Name -g $item.ResourceGroupName --query osProfile.computerName -o tsv
}
```

I have tested and it is working fine in my local environment and refer to the below screenshot for your reference.

[image]